# Use apply on a data class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I know how to use the apply function on a normal Kotlin class but have not been able to use it with a data class:

```
data class Person(name: String)

val person = Person().apply {
    name = "Tony Stark" 
}
```

I get a compile message of:

> No value passed for parameter 'name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `name` is a constructor parameter only and not made a property, which is invalid for the data class concept anyway. Fix like this:

```
data class Person(val name: String)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `apply` function works similar with any class. But there are some errors in your code snippet:

1. Parameter in `Person` constructor didn't mentioned as `var` or `val`, so there is no fields `name` in that class. It would be better to make it `var` to be able to change value.
2. You made class's constructor with 1 parameter, but trying to use empty constructor - it is error.